# OBSOLETE - List Area51 discuss in the StackAuth sites list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stackauth, obsolete, area51

The API [works for](http://api.discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/1.0/help) Area 51 discuss, but it isn't listed on [the site list](http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites?type=jsontext). Would it be possible to add it so software using the API can access it without adding specific code for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discuss.area51 site is technically a meta with a non-standard parent.

That's really really weird, and I'm 100% certain there are [app]s out there that will break if we start returning a `state: linked_meta` site that has no parent.

That the API works against discuss.area51 is not guaranteed in the future either, we're not going to drop any ban hammers or anything for using it but its use is *unsupported*.

Comment: Then you just need to put its state as unlinked_meta. Or as a normal site, like MSO is.

Comment: Could the `'/stats'` method please return a proper `'sites'` object that contains `'logo_url'`, etc.?