# Is there any support for Area 51 in the new API?

Tags: support, api, api-v2, area51

Does the new API support Area 51? Will there be support in the future?

Comment: Duplicate of [Area 51 sites api](http://stackapps.com/q/2321/7653), and also [List Area51 discuss in the StackAuth sites list](http://stackapps.com/q/1957/7653), and also [Why I think Area51 needs an API](http://stackapps.com/q/1234/7653).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Area51 isn't in the API; it's different enough from the Q&A sites that it'd have to have a rather different one anyway.

There are currently no plans to make an Area51 API either.